# for the year ended/ending

Tags: word-usage, usage

Which is correct, ended or ending?

> The Consumer Price Index rose 8.5% for the year **ended**/**ending** in March, not adjusted for seasonal swings.

Answer (score 1):

> ...year ended/ending in March....

It has to be *ending*.  *ending* is a present participle, and the participle phrase *ending in March* acts as an adjective describing *year*.

To use *ended*, we could say

> The Consumer Price Index rose 8.5% for the year, **which** ended in March, not adjusted for seasonal swings.

The relative clause **which ended in March** acts as an adjective describing *year*.